# ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY giving Syntax error in mysql5.7

Tags: mysql, select, partition-by

I am using partition by to get duplicate rows and this query returning syntax error in mysql5.7

```
select column1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column2, column3 ORDER BY column2 DESC) as  RowNumber 
from tableA
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY column1, column2 ' at line 1
```

**Or any other query**

Or any other query that retrun the only rows that duplicates(both column2 and column 3 contains same values repectivley) in this case the output will return row 1, 3, 5, 6

All rows in table: [image: All rows in table]

Desired output by query: [image: Desired output by query]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Window functions are not supported in MySql 5.7

Comment: @forpas Thanks, can you please explain which one is window function ?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is a window function.

Comment: @forpas any other solution to get duplicates value rows(also want id in select that contains unique values)

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: @forpas Added samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where column1 <> t.column1 and column2 = t.column2 and column3 = t.column3
)
```

Comment: Thank for help. What do if I want to skip the first row of duplicated then what modification i need make in this query ? Suppose there is 2 rows duplicated then I want to get only second and if 3 then want to get last 2 by skip first. Thanks

Comment: Something like: `select t.* from tablename t
where t.column1 > (select min(column1) from tablename where column2 = t.column2 and column3 = t.column3)`

Comment: Thank you so much  for such and immediate reply